# How to make slider in bouncing ball game with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I want to create a game like A ball breaking block and at the bottom I have created a slider which reflect back the ball towards those bricks.

But this Slider which reflect back the ball towards the bricks if the ball collide with this slider. This slider works fine in laptop because of **e.key** but when it comes to mobile phone I have to make this slider which slides without need of any button I want to scroll this slider at **x-axis** but without any button in mobile phone is it possible to do this with touch sensitivity.

**This is what I want**  If someone hold the slider and slide towards right it move right side or I someone slide it towards left side so it's move left side and refect back the ball towards the brick and score more.

This is what I tried.

```js
 const rulesBtn = document.getElementById('rules-btn');
const closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-btn');
const rules = document.getElementById('rules');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let score = 0;

const brickRowCount = 9;
const brickColumnCount = 5;
const delay = 500; //delay to reset the game

// Create ball props
const ball = {
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2,
  size: 10,
  speed: 4,
  dx: 4,
  dy: -4,
  visible: true
};

// Create paddle props
const paddle = {
  x: canvas.width / 2 - 40,
  y: canvas.height - 20,
  w: 80,
  h: 10,
  speed: 8,
  dx: 0,
  visible: true
};

// Create brick props
const brickInfo = {
  w: 70,
  h: 20,
  padding: 10,
  offsetX: 45,
  offsetY: 60,
  visible: true
};

// Create bricks
const bricks = [];
for (let i = 0; i < brickRowCount; i++) {
  bricks[i] = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < brickColumnCount; j++) {
    const x = i * (brickInfo.w + brickInfo.padding) + brickInfo.offsetX;
    const y = j * (brickInfo.h + brickInfo.padding) + brickInfo.offsetY;
    bricks[i][j] = { x, y, ...brickInfo };
  }
}

// Draw ball on canvas
function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = ball.visible ? '#0095dd' : 'transparent';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

// Draw paddle on canvas
function drawPaddle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.w, paddle.h);
  ctx.fillStyle = paddle.visible ? '#0095dd' : 'transparent';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

// Draw score on canvas
function drawScore() {
  ctx.font = '20px Arial';
  ctx.fillText(`Score: ${score}`, canvas.width - 100, 30);
}

// Draw bricks on canvas
function drawBricks() {
  bricks.forEach(column => {
    column.forEach(brick => {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(brick.x, brick.y, brick.w, brick.h);
      ctx.fillStyle = brick.visible ? '#0095dd' : 'transparent';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
    });
  });
}

// Move paddle on canvas
function movePaddle() {
  paddle.x += paddle.dx;

  // Wall detection
  if (paddle.x + paddle.w > canvas.width) {
    paddle.x = canvas.width - paddle.w;
  }

  if (paddle.x < 0) {
    paddle.x = 0;
    }
}

// Move ball on canvas
function moveBall() {
  ball.x += ball.dx;
  ball.y += ball.dy;

  // Wall collision (right/left)
  if (ball.x + ball.size > canvas.width || ball.x - ball.size < 0) {
    ball.dx *= -1; // ball.dx = ball.dx * -1
  }

  // Wall collision (top/bottom)
  if (ball.y + ball.size > canvas.height || ball.y - ball.size < 0) {
    ball.dy *= -1;
  }

  // console.log(ball.x, ball.y);

  // Paddle collision
  if (
    ball.x - ball.size > paddle.x &&
    ball.x + ball.size < paddle.x + paddle.w &&
    ball.y + ball.size > paddle.y
  ) {
    ball.dy = -ball.speed;
  }

  // Brick collision
  bricks.forEach(column => {
    column.forEach(brick => {
      if (brick.visible) {
        if (
          ball.x - ball.size > brick.x && // left brick side check
          ball.x + ball.size < brick.x + brick.w && // right brick side check
          ball.y + ball.size > brick.y && // top brick side check
          ball.y - ball.size < brick.y + brick.h // bottom brick side check
        ) {
          ball.dy *= -1;
          brick.visible = false;

          increaseScore();
        }
      }
    });
  });

  // Hit bottom wall - Lose
  if (ball.y + ball.size > canvas.height) {
    showAllBricks();
    score = 0;
  }
}

// Increase score
function increaseScore() {
  score++;

  if (score % (brickRowCount * brickColumnCount) === 0) {

      ball.visible = false;
      paddle.visible = false;

      //After 0.5 sec restart the game
      setTimeout(function () {
          showAllBricks();
          score = 0;
          paddle.x = canvas.width / 2 - 40;
          paddle.y = canvas.height - 20;
          ball.x = canvas.width / 2;
          ball.y = canvas.height / 2;
          ball.visible = true;
          paddle.visible = true;
      },delay)
  }
}

// Make all bricks appear
function showAllBricks() {
  bricks.forEach(column => {
    column.forEach(brick => (brick.visible = true));
  });
}

// Draw everything
function draw() {
  // clear canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  drawBall();
  drawPaddle();
  drawScore();
  drawBricks();
}

// Update canvas drawing and animation
function update() {
  movePaddle();
  moveBall();

  // Draw everything
  draw();

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();

// Keydown event
function keyDown(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Right' || e.key === 'ArrowRight' ||) {
    paddle.dx = paddle.speed;
  } else if (e.key === 'Left' || e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
    paddle.dx = -paddle.speed;
  }
}

// Keyup event
function keyUp(e) {
  if (
    e.key === 'Right' ||
    e.key === 'ArrowRight' ||
    e.key === 'Left' ||
    e.key === 'ArrowLeft'||
    e.key==='touch'
  ) {
    paddle.dx = 0;
  }
}

// Keyboard event handlers
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp);
someElement.addEventListener('touchstart', process_touchstart,true);
someElement.addEventListener('touchmove', process_touchmove, true);


// Rules and close event handlers
rulesBtn.addEventListener('click', () => rules.classList.add('show'));
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => rules.classList.remove('show'));
```

```css
        * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #0095dd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #fff;
}

canvas {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #222;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}

.rules-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}

.rules {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  transform: translateX(-400px);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

.rules.show {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Breakout!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>

    </style>
    <h1>Breakout!</h1>
    <button id="rules-btn" class="btn rules-btn">Show Rules</button>
    <div id="rules" class="rules">
      <h2>How To Play:</h2>
      <p>
        Use your right and left keys to move the paddle to bounce the ball up
        and break the blocks.
      </p>
      <p>If you miss the ball, your score and the blocks will reset.</p>
      <button id="close-btn" class="btn">Close</button>
    </div>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a [mre]. You can basically remove everything except the slider.

Comment: @ChrisG well it's causing problems.